# Zend Paginator with query from string

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have complicated query to my database, which I run via raw SQL query. Not using zend orm. I'd like to add Zend Paginator for my query.

From Zend docs, I've found, that I need to give all records to Zend Paginator adapter, and he make `COUNT()` and `LIMIT` by his own.

I have situation like this:

```
$sql = 'complicated query'; //LIMIT added "by hand", I'd like to make it automatically via zend_paginator
$q = $db->fetchAll($sql, array(/*paramteres here*/));
```

Now my question is: how should I use Zend Paginator to make pagination? Which adapter should I use in my situation? It's not possible to manually fetching all rows and use array adapters (about 50000 records in table)

Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array but it's not the best way. Better way is to rewrite your query to Zend_Db_Select and use Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect

Comment: As I wrote, Array adapter is not an option. Too many records in result.

Comment: Use the second part of an answer then

Comment: Is rewriting a query to Zend_Db_Select the only way? Query is really complicated, and rewriting it to Db_select will cost a lot of time.

Comment: You can write your own adapter that will do 2 things - take your query ->remove all columns selected and use only one  SELECT COUNT(1) AS `count`... then operating this number will generate limit and offset for main query, but i think it's more complicated then rewriting query to Zend_Db_Select

Comment: Want to have your cake and eat it too then convert it to Zend_Db_Select.

Comment: Sorry for late response:) @Vadyus, it was quiet easy to implement custom adapter. One disadvantage is query code duplication (one for pagination, second for counting). Still, probably the best solution will be rewrite query to Db_Select. If there will be enough time, I'll convert it to Db_select. For now, custom adapter work's fine:) Thanks guys:)